# sails.io.js - nodejs - Resourceful PubSub not receiving model events

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am trying to subscribe a nodejs application to model events in sails. Here is my code:

```
var socketIOClient = require('socket.io-client'),
    sailsIOClient = require('sails.io.js');

var io = sailsIOClient(socketIOClient);

io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';

io.socket.on("agent", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
})

io.socket.get("/agent", function(resData, jwres) {})
```

Here is a link to all of the output on the sails server when the client(nodejs) connects:

https://gist.github.com/CiscoKidxx/e5af93ebcc24702ba4f8

My understanding is that when I create a new agent it should trigger a console.log(event) which lists the changes. This is not happening. I do get a "now connected to sails" upon script start up. Any thoughts?

Here is my call to create a new agent in my UserController:

```
Agent.create({
  syncToken: token,
  owner: user.id
}).exec(function (err, newAgent) {
  Agent.publishUpdate(newAgent.id, {syncToken: newAgent.syncToken});
```

Comment: How you are making changes to the `Agent` model? If you are making changes directly into database you need to use `.publishUpdate()`.

See http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/web-sockets/resourceful-pub-sub/publish-update

Comment: I'm making a new agent every time a user registers and associating the agent to the new user via the UserController.js I have included some of that code in my OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The server side code snippet above doesn't show a call to **Agent.publishCreate** in the callback, but rather a *publishUpdate*.

From what I understand, the publishCreate is only automatically triggered when using the blueprints - but not for programatic calls like your Agent.create above.

So changing it from publishUpdate to publishCreate might fix it in your context.